# How to get logged into a text file all files moved with a batch file with destination directory included in log?

Tags: batch-file

I've created a BAT file for moving files. There are 280+ distinct lines of code, each line of code follows this pattern:

```
move /-y "C:\Source Folder\*ABCD*.*" "D:\Destination\"
```

This part works fine. I also want a LOG for the files moved by the batch script. So I'm using currently following:

```
move /-y "C:\Source Folder\*ABCD*.*" "D:Destination\">>LOG.txt
```

But here is the issue: the LOG file entries look something like this:

> C:\Source Folder\ABCD1234.rar
>
> 1 file(s) moved.

I wanted the LOG file to contain also **the destination folder** which will be a huge help for error checking.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use in your batch file first the 2 lines:

```
echo Moving "C:\Source Folder\*ABCD*.*" to "D:\Destination\">LOG.txt
echo.>>LOG.txt
```

Next the existing lines follow with appending to `LOG.txt` what exactly is moved from source to destination folder now written to log file in first line.

The entire batch file looks for example as follows:

```
@echo off

echo Moving "C:\Source Folder\*ABCD*.*" to "D:\Destination\">LOG.txt
echo.>>LOG.txt
move /-y "C:\Source Folder\*ABCD*.*" "D:\Destination\">>LOG.txt
echo.>>LOG.txt

echo Moving "C:\Other Folder\*.*" to "D:\OtherDestination\">>LOG.txt
echo.>>LOG.txt
move /-y "C:\Other Folder\*.*" "D:\OtherDestination\">>LOG.txt
```

Comment: I tested your code out, the LOG file lists only the following line:"Moving "C:\Source Folder\ABCD*.*" to "D:\Destination\", it doesn't say which file it's actually moving..